# Why is PtrToStringUni returning some incorrect characters

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services, pinvoke, marshalling

I'm trying to use advapi32.dll via pinvoke in my C# application to get the path to an executable used by a service. I'm specifying Unicode and getting parts of what appear to be a path, but some of the characters are clearly getting garbaled in the translation.

```
private static string GetServicePath(IntPtr service)
{
    SERVICE_CONFIG status = new SERVICE_CONFIG();

    uint bytesNeeded = 1;
    var queryResult = QueryServiceConfig(service, status, 0, out bytesNeeded);
    if (queryResult == 0 && bytesNeeded == 0)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Failed to query service config.");
    }
    else
    {
        QueryServiceConfig(service, status, bytesNeeded, out bytesNeeded);
    }

    var servicePath = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(status.lpBinaryPathName);
    return servicePath;
}
```

^ Method being called to get Service name using a handle to the service

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private class SERVICE_CONFIG
{
    public int dwServiceType;
    public ServiceStartType dwStartType;
    public int dwErrorControl;
    public IntPtr lpBinaryPathName;
    public IntPtr lpLoadOrderGroup;
    public int dwTagID;
    public IntPtr lpDependencies;
    public IntPtr lpServiceStartName;
    public IntPtr lpDisplayName;
};

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern int QueryServiceConfig(IntPtr hService, SERVICE_CONFIG queryConfig, UInt32 cbBufSize, out UInt32 pcbBytesNeeded);
```

^ Relevant PInvoke Method and Structure

So for example, I would expect asking the for "Bonjour Service" path to return

`"C:\Program Files\Bonjour\mDNSResponder.exe"`

instead I get this on Windows 10

`"C:\??? , m Files\Bonjour\mDNSResponder.exe"`

and this on Windows 8

`"C:\??? , "C:\??? , "C:\??? , "C:\??? , "C:\`

and just this on XP

`"C??`

If I try to convert any of the other properties like Display Name or Start Name then I get a legitimate string. Why isn't the executable path resolving the way the other strings do?

Comment: Why have you marked the string as `IntPtr` instead of `string` where you wouldn’t even need to call PtrToStringUni?

Comment: @ckuri Marshalling straight to string hasn't worked at all, there's a CLR exception when I've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you're supposed to *allocate* a buffer, not pass a fixed buffer size. All the strings pointer in QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG will be contained in that buffer.

QueryServiceConfig will tell you how big the buffer must be. A native example is available here: [Querying a Service's Configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684928.aspx)

So, I have modified your code accordingly:

```
    private static string GetServicePath(IntPtr service)
    {
        QueryServiceConfig(service, IntPtr.Zero, 0, out int size);
        if (size == 0)
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

        var ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
        try
        {
            if (!QueryServiceConfig(service, ptr, size, out size))
                throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

            var config = Marshal.PtrToStructure<QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG>(ptr);
            return config.lpBinaryPathName;
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
        }
    }

    // note that I use a struct, not a class, so I can call Marshal.PtrToStructure.
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private struct QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG
    {
        public int dwServiceType;
        public int dwStartType;
        public int dwErrorControl;
        public string lpBinaryPathName;
        public string lpLoadOrderGroup;
        public int dwTagID;
        public string lpDependencies;
        public string lpServiceStartName;
        public string lpDisplayName;
    };

    // return type is a bool, no need for an int here
    // user SetLastError when the doc says so
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool QueryServiceConfig(IntPtr hService, IntPtr lpServiceConfig, int cbBufSize, out int pcbBytesNeeded);
```

Comment: This works, thanks. Still not sure I understand the distinction though that makes this work. I inherited this code and I'd like to better understand why allocating the memory and marshalling a ptr to structure is more effective than having ptrs in a class and converting them to strings.

Comment: In fact, you don't have the choice. You *must* allocate what QueryServiceConfig tells you to allocate. The size of this buffer is much bigger than the size of the struct/class itself. It will then fill that buffer, including strings content. It will then set strings references in the structure to point to string content *inside* that allocated buffer. You had errors because you allocated nothing but the class size itself. Also, you could use IntPtr instead of string if you prefer, but that useless. It's easier to let the CLR transform the buffer into the final types.